# Infinite redirect loop after cloning Heroku Rails app and putting on new domain with SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, heroku, amazon-route53

So here's the situation: I have a heroku rails app (let's call it `original_app`) sitting on a custom domain sitting at `http://www.originaldomain.com`. It is a standard Rails 4.2.0 app running on PG/Passenger/Nginx. The domain is hosted on DNSimple (with the root domain aliased to the Heroku SSL endpoint and the www CNAMEd to the endpoint) and it has an approved SSL certificate. The production.rb file forces the app to remain in SSL. This app works fine, without any problems.

THEN, I used the `heroku fork` command to "clone" the `original_app` to an identical app on heroku called, say, `new_app`. I purchased an SSL certificate from Godaddy for `www.newdomain.com` and provisioned it on the heroku SSL endpoint addon. The domain `newdomain.com` is hosted on AWS's Route 53 service. Because they don't allow for redirecting of the root (a.k.a. "zone apex"), I used a workaround detailed here [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53] (which was a solution to a similar question posted on stack overflow) to alias `newdomain.com` root to `www.newdomain.com` via A record alias to an S3 bucket that redirects to `www.newdomain.com`. Meanwhile, on Route 53, `www.newdomain.com` redirects to the Heroku SSL endpoint URL.

PROBLEM: Whenever I access `https://www.newdomain.com/somepath`, I get a "too many redirects" error from the browser. Strangely enough, if I access the app directly at `https://new_app.herokuapp.com`, it works like a charm. And so does the original app. How is this possible if they're all identical?

Additional details:

- The home page works (e.g. `https://www.newdomain.com/`) because it is actually a static page hosted on a github.io repository. The rails app redirects to it and other static pages via a Rack::ReverseProxy in config.ru. It's the non-static pages that are the problem.
- If I do a `wget` command it shows the redirections bouncing back and forth between AWS (presumably Route53 and/or S3) and the Heroku Nginx/Passenger server. Here is an excerpt of the log:

  `bash
  $ wget --server-response https://www.newdomain.com/somepath -O -
  --2015-09-13 02:09:22--  https://www.newdomain.com/somepath
  Resolving www.newdomain.com... [IP address hidden for SO], [IP address hidden for SO]
  Connecting to www.newdomain.com|[IP address hidden for SO]|:443... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: text/html
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Status: 301 Moved Permanently
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
    X-Request-Id: 164c641d-c1f9-432b-aead-236dffa931a4
    Location: http://newdomain.com/somepath
    X-Runtime: 0.003392
    Date: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:09:22 GMT
    X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.6
    Server: nginx/1.6.2 + Phusion Passenger 5.0.6
    Via: 1.1 vegur
  Location: http://newdomain.com/somepath [following]
  --2015-09-13 02:09:22--  http://newdomain.com/somepath
  Resolving newdomain.com... [IP address hidden for SO]
  Connecting to newdomain.com|[IP address hidden for SO]|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    x-amz-id-2: tk7HsFoqcqgMtLwtofrFIE1ob1+gP50m1k6yo3f4Prinufu5w4R6lrsvPexFiCAyDSCO1c/OKwU=
    x-amz-request-id: 9357AE308083C80D
    Date: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:09:24 GMT
    Location: http://www.newdomain.com/somepath
    Content-Length: 0
    Server: AmazonS3
  Location: http://www.newdomain.com/somepath [following]
  --2015-09-13 02:09:23--  http://www.newdomain.com/somepath
  Connecting to www.newdomain.com|[IP address hidden for SO]|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 0
    Status: 301 Moved Permanently
    Location: https://www.newdomain.com/somepath
    Date: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:09:23 GMT
    X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.6
    Server: nginx/1.6.2 + Phusion Passenger 5.0.6
    Via: 1.1 vegur
  Location: https://www.newdomain.com/somepath [following]
  --2015-09-13 02:09:23--  https://www.newdomain.com/somepath
  Connecting to www.newdomain.com|[IP address hidden for SO]|:443... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: text/html
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Status: 301 Moved Permanently
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
    X-Request-Id: daf02b75-0d2d-4880-8a3d-e61b648d2a86
    Location: http://newdomain.com/somepath
    X-Runtime: 0.003992
    Date: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:09:23 GMT
    X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.6
    Server: nginx/1.6.2 + Phusion Passenger 5.0.6
    Via: 1.1 vegur
  Location: http://newdomain.com/somepath [following]
  --2015-09-13 02:09:23--  http://newdomain.com/somepath
  Connecting to newdomain.com|[IP address hidden for SO]|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    x-amz-id-2: uyB1ckI+koqGzKFjTVLatqpJ0cpgAjubGpla62w+8yKpz363FTv6ogtQuzo8tibKKyjAM4X7k3I=
    x-amz-request-id: BED63CC152C82099
    Date: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:09:24 GMT
    Location: http://www.newdomain.com/somepath
    Content-Length: 0
    Server: AmazonS3
  Location: http://www.newdomain.com/somepath [following]
  --2015-09-13 02:09:23--  http://www.newdomain.com/somepath
  Connecting to www.newdomain.com|[IP address hidden for SO]|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 0
    Status: 301 Moved Permanently
    Location: https://www.newdomain.com/somepath
    Date: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:09:23 GMT
    X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.6
    Server: nginx/1.6.2 + Phusion Passenger 5.0.6
    Via: 1.1 vegur`

  Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: I solved it. It turns out someone had installed this gem on the app: https://github.com/stjhimy/rack-www and set `config.middleware.use Rack::WWW, :www => false` in application.rb